# MS Access Get next UID

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

with C# currently I'm attempting to pull the highest UID number in the column. I need to get the highest UID + 1 to create the next user. Help would be appreciated.

```html
UID:
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Why not use an [AutoNumber column](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-autonumber-field-as-a-primary-key-96ba683b-7f86-4354-aa25-3849f5e5b641)

Comment: @stuartd how would I do that?